# .NET 6 Blazor Web Server Globalization

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I wanted to know how do you implement Multilanguage Globalization, I have one resource file with different translations for each and every word and I don't want to create a resource file for each and every component. If any procedures are available please let me know.

Thank you

I tried Localization of the Blazor Server but ended up doing creating a resource file for each and every component which makes the code non-maintainable and any minor changes regarding the resources, I will have to change it in all the components resource files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.